# Are rotation matrices tensors?

Tags: reference-frames, tensor-calculus, rotation

Are rotation matrices tensors? If no, why?
I'm not sure about it, for example considering the $z$-axis rotation matrix when I rotate the coordinate system the rotation matrix around the old $z$-axis change form.

Comment: Matrices are never tensors. Some tensors can be represented by matrices. Tensors are multilinear maps and not matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for an Euclidean 3D space the rotations (and translations) are maps between reference frames, while tensors are independent of reference frames. See also my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/463142/2451) in the context of SR.