# What is an example of a matrix that does not represent a tensor of rank $2$?

Tags: tensor-calculus

I often read that every tensor of order $2$ can be represented as a matrix (I do understand that). *But not every matrix is the representation of some second order tensor*. I am not sure, if I understand that correctly. Is it just that any matrix that represents a second order tensor has to be quadratic, i.e. a $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: Related: [Are matrices and second rank tensors the same thing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20437/2451) and links therein.

Comment: Where did you read that? It's not really correct.