How to use the definition of a rank-$2$ tensor for this kind of examples?
Suppose that, a rank-$2$ tensor transforms as
\begin{align}
T'^{ij}=\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^k}\frac{\partial x'^k}{\partial x^l}T^{kl}.
\end{align}
How to use this criterion to investigate if the following $2\times2$ matrix (as an example) represents a tensor?
\begin{bmatrix}
    xy       & 1  \\
    x^2-y^2       & e^x  \\
   \end{bmatrix}
Note that:

I think this example could be so useful because most textbooks prefer not to illustrate details. In fact, the question is: How (practically) one can find that, when a "thing" is a tensor or not?
This could be a good exercise and clarify many ambiguities. Since the focus is on this specific example, there will not be any duplication.


The question does not make sense: a matrix is not a tensor.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20437/2451 and links therein.

Please clarify what you mean. A tensor is a multilinear map from copies of $V$ and $V^$ to the underlying field. Simply writing down a matrix does not make a tensor. Even if you interpret a matrix as a map $V \otimes V^ \to \mathbb{R}$ you need to provide a basis. A tensor comprises components and basis.

Too long for a comment.

In the coordinate system where you label your coordinates by $(x,y)$ any $2\times 2$-matrix  whose elements are functions of $(x,y)$ gives rise to the four tensors
$$\tag1
a_{ij}\,dx^i\otimes dx^j\,,\quad a_i{}^j\,dx^i\otimes\partial_j\,,\quad a^i{}_j\,\partial_i\otimes dx^j\,,\quad a^{ij}\partial_i\otimes\partial_j
$$
(I wrote $(x,y)=(x^1,x^2)\,.$)

When you change the coordinates the components $a$ change. In case of $a^{ij}$ they change by a formula like you wrote it in OP.

You may want to verify this in the example of the Euclidean metric in Cartesian and polar coordinates:
$$
\mathbf{g}=dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy=dr\otimes dr+r^2\,d\theta\otimes d\theta.
$$

For tensors whose components are derivatives it is typically required that their components are derivatives in all coordinate systems. This leads to the concept of covariant derivative which is well-known.

As a little exercise you could take the transformation rules
\begin{align}
\partial_r&=\cos\theta\,\partial_x+\sin\theta\,\partial_y\,,&\partial_\theta&=-r\sin\theta\,\partial_x+r\cos\theta\,\partial_y\,,\\[2mm]
dx&=\cos\theta\,dr-r\sin\theta\,d\theta\,, &dy&=\sin\theta\,dr+r\cos\theta\,d\theta
\end{align}
then transform $dx\otimes \partial_x$ and so on and obtain all four tensors from (1) in polar coordinates.


